# Apply dplyr function to all but one column

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a data frame with numeric values in all columns except for the last one, how can I compute the mean across the row?

In this example, I am using all columns, including the `name` column which I would like to omit.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:40, ncol=10)) %>%
    mutate(name=LETTERS[1:4]) %>%
    mutate(mean=rowMeans(.))
```

Desired data frame output:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 mean name
1  1  5  9 13 17 21 25 29 33  37   19    A
2  2  6 10 14 18 22 26 30 34  38   20    B
3  3  7 11 15 19 23 27 31 35  39   21    C
4  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36  40   22    D
```

Comment: I would probably do this with `apply` (ie, `apply(df[, 1:10], 1, mean)`)

Comment: Not everything is about `dplyr` in life, just do `df$Mean <- rowMeans(df[-ncol(df)])` and get over with. Though if you insist, I think the idiomatic way will be something like `df %>% select(-ncol(df)) %>% mutate(Mean = rowMeans(.))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I really think both of those are viable answers. You should convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Your `dplyr`suggestion would remove `name` from the end result and not match OP desired output.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré yes, I saw that later but couldnt edit. Your approach is probably the idiomatic way, except I find it way too much typing for just calculate `rowMeans` on a data set

Comment: @DavidArenburg Agreed. I would also go with base R as you suggest. You should convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(mean = select(., -matches("name")) %>% rowMeans(.))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your setting, you could use

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:40, ncol=10)) %>%
  mutate(name=LETTERS[1:4]) %>%
  mutate(mean=rowMeans(.[,1:10]))
```